# ListView sorting by wrong column

Tags: c++, c, sorting, listview, winapi

In this winapi program, I am sorting all the items based on the "Date" column. However, it is sorting by the "Description" column instead of the "Date" column.
[image: This is how my listview looks]

Here is the code in WM_NOTIFY:

```
static char szText[10];
NM_LISTVIEW *pNm = (NM_LISTVIEW *)lParam;

switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code) {
    case LVN_COLUMNCLICK:
        if (pNm->iSubItem == 2)
            if (ListView_SortItems(pNm->hdr.hwndFrom, CompareFunc, 
                               (LPARAM) (pNm->iSubItem)) == FALSE)
                MessageBox(hwnd, "FALSE", "", MB_OK);
        break;
 /* other WM_NOTIFY code */
}
```

`ListView_SortItems` returns TRUE, strangely.
Here is the CompareFunc function:

```
int CALLBACK CompareFunc(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, LPARAM lParamSort)
{
    if (lParamSort == 2) {
        date d1, d2;              // app-defined "date" class
        char b1[32], b2[32];

        sscanf((char *) lParam1, "%s %d %d", b1, &d1.day, &d1.yr);
        sscanf((char *) lParam2, "%s %d %d", b2, &d2.day, &d2.yr);

        d1.month = monthtoi(b1);    // converts month as string to number
        d2.month = monthtoi(b2);

        if (d1 > d2)                // overloading the ">" and "<" operators
            return 1;
        else if (d1 < d2)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I tried checking iSubItem against 3 rather than 2 (1-based vs 0-based), but that didn't work either.
What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

```
int monthtoi(char *s)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        // MONTHS is a global array of char *, containing the months
        if (strcmp(MONTHS[i], s) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
bool date::operator>(const date &x)
{
    switch (this->cmp(x)) { // cmp is a private member function
    case 0:
    case -1:
        return false;
    case 1:
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool date::operator<(const date &x)
{
    switch (this->cmp(x)) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        return false;
    case -1:
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int date::cmp(const date &x)
{
    if (this->yr > x.yr)
        return 1;
    else if (this->yr < x.yr)
        return -1;

    if (this->yr == x.yr) {
        if (this->month > x.month)
            return 1;
        else if (this->month < x.month)
            return -1;
        else if (this->day > x.day)
            return 1;
        else if (this->day < x.day)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since we cannot see the implementation for `monthtoi` or your `operator>` implementation, there's little help to be expected. We also cannot see your `LVITEM`s. Are the `lParam` members properly set up?

Comment: Changed the answer @IInspectable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input `lParam1` and `lParam2` are not the string of the sub-item but as the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925158.aspx) says they are the data associated with the item:

> The lParam1 parameter is the 32-bit value associated with the first
>   item being compared; and the lParam2 parameter is the value associated
>   with the second item. These are the values that were specified in the
>   lParam member of the items' LVITEM structure when they were inserted
>   into the list.

You can find a complete ListView sorting example [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/250614) but the basics of it are as follows:

```
          // Custom type storing the item's information, or a link to it
struct myitemdata_t 
{
    char* pFood;
    char* pDescription;
    date  Date;
    ...
};

     // When adding items to a listview set the item data
m_ctlListView.InsertItem(i, "food");
m_ctlListView.SetItemText(i, 1, "Saturday shopping");
...
     // Set the item data for the list item
m_ctlListView.SetItemData(i, (LPARAM) GetItemData(i));

    // Your sort function should look like
int CALLBACK SortFunc(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, LPARAM lParamSort)
{
    myitemdata_t* pData1 = (myitemdata_t *)lParam1;
    myitemdata_t* pData2 = (myitemdata_t *)lParam2;
    ...
```